# Qt set style for all objects but one

Tags: c++, css, qt

I've currently got this style for all push buttons:

```
this->setStyleSheet(".QPushButton { background-color: #416eb6; color: #ddd; }");
```

This is great because it allows me to keep a constant styling for all the `QPushButton`'s without having to style them individually.

An issue arises when I need to style a `QPushButton` representing a color chooser. The button should represent the color that was chosen from the color chooser, but instead it just keeps the initial style that I set.

**Things I have tried:**

Giving an empty style sheet for the item:

```
this->setStyleSheet(#m_colorChooserButton { });
```

Setting the style to initial:

```
this->setStyleSheet(#m_colorChooserButton { background-color: initial});
```

Using a similar `css` selector `:not`:

```
this->setStyleSheet(".QPushButton:not(#m_colorChooserButton) { background-color: #416eb6; color: #ddd; }");
```

**Is there any way to achieve this result?**

I'd like to mimic the `:not` selector if possible since that's the most straightforward, but at this point, I'd do anything that works.

I'd like to **avoid** having to manually specify the style for each button I want it to show on, as there are well over 100 buttons and finding the object names of these buttons is very time consuming (large legacy code base).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 choices: apply a stylesheet to just that button and invalidate/reapply it every time you change the selected colour or just subclass that button and reimplement the paintevent:

```
class ColorButton : public QPushButton{
Q_OBJECT
Q_DISABLE_COPY(ColorButton)
public:
    ColorButton(QWidget* parent = Q_NULLPTR)
        :QPushButton(parent)
        ,m_color(Qt::red)
    {}
    const QColor& color() const {return m_color;}
    void setColor(const QColor& val){if(m_color==val) return; m_color=val; update();}
protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
    {
        QStylePainter p(this);
        QStyleOptionButton option;
        initStyleOption(&option);
        option.palette.setColor(m_color,QPalette::Background);
        p.drawControl(QStyle::CE_PushButton, option);
    }
private:
    QColor m_color;
};
```

P.S.
The KDE API already has that widget: https://api.kde.org/frameworks-api/frameworks-apidocs/frameworks/kwidgetsaddons/html/classKColorButton.html

Comment: The local stylesheet solution is more simple to read&write than your example in my opinion :)